# NullPointerException when creating a infinite carousel in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a infinite scrollable carousel of cards using modified version of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70303230/1305267)

```
@Composable
fun CircularList(
    items: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(
            count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
            itemContent = {
                val index = it % items.size  // line X
                Text(text = items[index]) 
            }
        )
    }
}
```

However, this crashes with NPE:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListItemProviderImplKt$generateKeyToIndexMap$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
```

This will also crash, if i use a smaller index of 500 for example, but it doesn't crash, if i use 50

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState(500) // Crashes
val listState = rememberLazyListState(50)  // Doesn't crash
```

What could possible cause this?

EDIT1: I have tried debugging it with breakpoints and it crashes before it stops on line X. Items list is not empty, usual test size is 2-6 objects.

EDIT2: Also tried using scrollToItem() instead to set the initial index, but that returned the same exception

Comment: The code looks fine, it would crash if you pass an empty list though, but still won't give NPA. Is there something you're missing to share?

Comment: Debug by setting breakpoint on line "val index = it % items.size". I think "it" is null which is not expected

Comment: I've modified the question a bit to include more info. List is not empty and i have tried to debug it with breakpoint, but it crashes before it stops on that line. Even if the it is null, what's the reason for it? It shouldn't be and it isn't if i set the initialFirstVisibleItemIndex to 50?

Answer (score 0):

I never did understand why this problem occurred, but here's a solution (or workaround/hack) how to solve it:

```
@Composable
fun CircularList(
    items: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 4) // Use smaller index for smaller count

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(
            count = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2, // Use smaller count, somewhere around 1B
            itemContent = {
                val index = it % items.size  
                Text(text = items[index]) 
            }
        )
    }
}
```

For some reason, this worked without a problem.